# Prolog last element function returns whole list

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment to implement quicksort in Prolog then return the final element. I have the quicksort working but when it gets to the last element call it returns the whole list. My last element works when run on its own but not when I call it at the end of quicksort. Any ideas as to what I need to change?

```
quicksort([],[]).
quicksort([H|T],Final) :- 
    partition(T,H,Left,Right), 
    quicksort(Left,Ls),                           
    quicksort(Right,Rs), 
    append(Ls,[H|Rs],Sorted), 
    lastelement(Final, [Sorted]).

partition([],Pivot,[],[]).
partition([H|T],Pivot,[H|Ls],Rs) :- H =< Pivot, partition(T,Pivot,Ls,Rs).
partition([H|T],Pivot,Ls,[H|Rs]) :- H > Pivot, partition(T,Pivot,Ls,Rs).

append([],Sorted,Sorted).
append([H|T],Sorted,[H|Z]) :- append(T,Sorted,Z).

lastelement(Final, [Final]).
lastelement(Final, [_|T]):- lastelement(Final,T).
```

Comment: Remove the brackets from the call `lastelement(Final, [Sorted])`

Comment: I tried that but it returns false

Comment: Then you probably have another issue before calling lastelement. Are you sure you removed the brackets from the call ? It should read `lastelement(Final, Sorted)`

Comment: Yes I removed  the brackets so it reads exactly like that but returns false.

Comment: Then you should check the other parts of your program. The second argument of quicksort is a list for the first clause and an item for the second one. I think you are mixing the two parts of your assignment. First compute quicksort which should have a list as the second argument. Then call lastelement to get the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed by @gusbro, it's not possible to define a recursive predicate whose **base case** produces a list and whose **recursive step** produces an element. Thus, a possible solution is:

```
quicksort([],[]).
quicksort([H|T], Sorted) :-
    mypartition(T, H, Left, Right),
    quicksort(Left,  Ls),
    quicksort(Right, Rs),
    myappend(Ls, [H|Rs], Sorted).

mypartition([], _Pivot,[],[]).
mypartition([H|T],Pivot,[H|Ls],Rs) :- H =< Pivot, mypartition(T,Pivot,Ls,Rs).
mypartition([H|T],Pivot,Ls,[H|Rs]) :- H > Pivot, mypartition(T,Pivot,Ls,Rs).

myappend([], Sorted, Sorted).
myappend([H|T], Sorted, [H|Z]) :- myappend(T, Sorted, Z).

lastelement(Final, [Final]).
lastelement(Final, [_|T]):- lastelement(Final,T).

quicksort_last(List, Last) :-
    quicksort(List, Sorted),
    lastelement(Last, Sorted).
```

Examples:

```
?- quicksort([61,46,59,27,12,38], S).
S = [12, 27, 38, 46, 59, 61] ;
false.

?- quicksort_last([61,46,59,27,12,38], S).
S = 61 ;
false.
```

**A BETTER SOLUTION**

The average complexity time of `quicksort_last/2` is O(n lg n). Supposing that your solution **must** be basead on the idea of *Quick Sort*, a more **efficient** approach, with average complexity time O(n), is:

- To have a last item (aka, *maximum item*), the complete sorted list cannot be empty.
- After the partition:

  - If the right sublist is empty, then Pivot is the last element in the complete sorted list (because Pivot is **bigger** than all elements in the *left* sublist).
  - Otherwise, the last element in the right sublist is also the last element in the complete sorted list (because, if there is at least one item in the *right* sublist, then Pivot is **smaller** than it).

```
quick_last([Pivot|Rest], Last) :-
    mypartition(Rest, Pivot, _, Right),
    (   Right = []
    ->  Last = Pivot
    ;   quick_last(Right, Last) ).
```

Examples:

```
?- quick_last([61,46,59,27,12,38], S).
S = 61 ;
false.

?- quick_last([71, 100, 83, 97, 62, 6, 42, 3, 40], L).
L = 100 ;
false.
```

In the best case, at each recursive call of `quick_last/2`, the length of the list is divided by 2. Since the time consumed by `partition/4` is proportional to the length of the list, we have T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 ≈ 2*n.

**REMARK** This solution is a particular case of an algorithm to find the *k*-th smallest element in an unordered list (see: [quick-select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)).

Comment: If you only want the largest number of a list instead of `quick_last/2` you might just go through the list keeping the largest number found, no need to sort anything for that.

Comment: @gusbro Of course that is true (actually it's obvious), but it is also true that if you only need the last element of an ordered list, you also don't need to sort it to find out what that element is. In my answer, I have assumed that this is a problem with a didact goal, that only aims to adapt the idea of the quicksort algorithm to solve another problem.

Comment: @gusbro I don't know if you noticed, but the OP is to create a predicate based on quicksort that sorts the list and returns only the last element of the sorted list (so the work of sorting the entire list is unnecessary, but using quicksort is not).

Comment: @gusbro Of interest (quick-select): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickselect-algorithm/

Comment: @slago Thank you so much your solution worked, can't believe I couldn't see that. You're right it makes no sense to sort the list then to only care about the last element but that is the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

lastElement/2 seems to be trying to find the last element from the sorted list...and pass it back as the list itself in the various recursive calls. `quicksort(Left,Ls)`, for example, is called as though Ls is going to be a sorted version of Left, but it actually returns the last element of that list.

If you want that last element, sure, you can do it, but you can get it after you've done quicksort. (Or find it some other way, to be sure.)

```
quicksort([H|T],Sorted) :- partition(T,H,Left,Right), 
                           quicksort(Left,Ls),
                           quicksort(Right,Rs), 
                           append(Ls,[H|Rs],Sorted).

findLastElement(List,Final) :- quicksort(List,Sorted), lastelement(Final, Sorted).
```